# code render block in asp.net with server side control not working

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web

in my application i need to use foreach to create table row every type i want to add button i want to bind that CommandName with item data to it's give error

```
 <table  border="1" style="font-size:small;height:auto;">
         <%foreach (var item in vm)
           {%>
           <tr>
               <td><a  href="<%=item.FilePath %>"><%=item.FileName %></a></td>
                <td><%=item.UserName %></td>
                <td><%=item.Association %></td>
                <td><%=item.Size %></td>
                <td><%=item.UpdoadedOn %></td>
                <td><asp:Button ID="btn" Text="delete" OnClick="delete_Click" runat="server" CommandName='<%=item.Id %>' /></td>
           </tr>    
           <%} %>
      </table>
```

---

```
CommandName='<%=item.Id %>'
```

is there any other way to do that....??

Comment: What is the error?  Which line throws it? Also, this looks like a Razor view. Are you using MVC?

Comment: Why can't you use a repeater and databind `vm` to it in the code behind? You will be able to use the `OnItemDataBind` event to set values.

Comment: @jadarnel27 - This is webforms (note the title - server side control).  The issue is with using `<%=%>` on a server side control - this is not possible.

Comment: Ah, must be my mistake, @Oded. I just haven't seen people use that kind of syntax (the foreach part) in webforms. I did see "server side controls" in the title, but I have seen people (especially people new to the technology) type one when they mean the other on here.

Comment: Putting it here that I've found that code render blocks do not function within the tag of an ASP.NET control. Tried all sorts of things. They either caused the control to not be recognised at all, or just came out as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use a Button control, use a link instead.

Replace:

```
<td><asp:Button ID="btn" Text="delete" OnClick="delete_Click"
runat="server" CommandName='<%=item.Id %>' /></td>
```

with:

```
<td><a class="button-link" href="/item/delete/<%=item.Id %>">Delete</a></td>
```